# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(13)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

my WordPress site is not loading, it's getting this error:

> Could not successfully run query (SELECT name, value FROM wp_simple_shortcodes WHERE 1) from wp_simple_shortcodes: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(13)

I am told it is because MySQL extension is now deprecated.

My WordPress (and plugins) are up to date so should be running MySQLI already. My hosting company said I need to update my code from my MySQL to MySQLI to fix the issue. But I never wrote any custom code for this site at all and I am a complete beginner with PHP.

What files do I need to update? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more likely this has something to do with the database server running on the webserver of your hosting company. Maybe they've updated the MySQL server version or they changed some PHP settings.

You should ask them to check the PHP and MySQL config settings and to restart both the webserver and the database server. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I tried talking to them earlier and they added this snippet to the config file "define('WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', true);”, saying it was only a temporary fix and I will need to update the code to use MYSQLI. Then I proceeded to spend hours trying to figure what code they are talking about because I did not write any PHP myself and everything is up to date. I will ask them to try your recommendations tomorrow, I hope it will fix it

Comment: WordPress uses MySQLi as the default connection method when 1) the MySQLi extension is installed on the webserver and 2) the webserver runs PHP version 5.5 or later OR the `WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL` constant is set to `false`. Setting the `WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL` constant to `true` causes WordPress to use the MySQL extension instead of the MySQLi extension.

Comment: OK thank you. I figured out it was caused from an outdated plugin called "Simple Shortcodes" using a old version of PHP.